# Which Storage administration course will be better?

Tags: storage, ibm, netapp, tivoli

I am working as a Linux admin. I would like to do a course in storage administration.

Which should be the better certification path for me IBM tivoli or netapp ?

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you go on a course for the products you actually have and manage or are planning to do so. Just going on any old course will teach you somethings but not that much and it will be frustrating for you to attend the course then have no further experience - it's this experience of real running systems that will educate you the most.

Answer (score 3):

Chopper3 made the most important point here. However, if you don't know what you are going to be managing, [SNIA](http://www.snia.org/home/) is the starting point, as it is vendor-agnostic, and give plenty of generic SAN knowledge